Can I have a hyperlink in a Power Apps table control?
Is it possible to have a hyperlink in a Power Apps table control?
I would like users to click a link that goes to a SharePoint site.
If not, what controls are the alternatives?
Thanks in advance.

Are you talking about classic "Data table" control in Power Apps?

No the new table control

If you are asking about classic data table control, there is an IsHyperlink property available for columns inside the data table control.
You can write formula like below on OnSelect property of particular column to open link in new browser tab:
Launch(DataTable1.Selected.'Link to item', {}, LaunchTarget.New)



If you are asking about modern table control, there is no property available for hyperlinks.
However, you can write formula like below on OnSelect property of table control to open link in new browser tab. Link will be opened on click of any column within the table control:
Launch(Table2.Selected.'Link to item', {}, LaunchTarget.New)



Thanks Ganesh. So it seems with the new tablemodern control  you can only control a selected row not a column like with the Datatable. Is this the case?

Yes correct. Almost all modern controls have some limitations compared to classic controls.
